# Como obtener los identificadores que hay en los nombres de los archivos csv en bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, git-bash

Estoy intentando recorrer varios archivos csv, los archivos csv tienen el siguiente formato:

```
XX_XXX01_XX.csv
XX_XXX02_XX.csv
XX_XXX03_XX.csv
XX_XXX04_XX.csv
```

y lo que quiero conseguir es obtener los numeros que hay en cada nombre del csv:

salida:

```
01
02
03
04
```

Lo he intentado de la siguiente forma y no me ha funcionado, también lo he intentado con cut, pero tampoco me fucniona. No sé en que fallo

```
for i in $(ls)
do

         echo "$i" | awk -F '{print $1}' $i

done
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo con expresiones regulares:

```
expreg="[a-zA-Z]{2}_[a-zA-Z]{3}([0-9]{2})_[a-zA-Z]{2}\.csv"

for nombre in $(ls)
do
    if [[ "$nombre" =~ $expreg ]]
    then
        echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    fi
done
```

- [a-zA-z] representa cualquier letra
- [a-zA-z]{n} es cualquier letra repetida n veces
- [0-9]{2} es cualquier dígito repetido dos veces, y los paréntesis alrededor es para capturar la expresión que coincida con esa parte
- \.csv es, literalmente, la extensión `.csv` (hay que escapar el punto porque tiene un significado especial en una expresión regular)

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que cada caracter será uno NO NUMÉRICO salvo esos que quieres extraer específicamente, puedes resolverlo con una sencilla expresión regular con `grep`:

```bash
ls <ruta de tu directorio> | grep -Po "\d+"
```

Si lo que quieres es para puro archivo con terminación `.csv`.

```
ls /mi ruta/*.csv | grep -Po "\d+"
```

Lo que hace `grep` es filtrar el texto que le pase por el *stdin*, y sus parámetros le indican lo siguiente:

- "-P", usa expresiones regulares tipo Perl: esto lo hago para que que la expresión regular sea menos verbosa
- "-o", para sólo imprimir los caracteres *matcheados* por la expresión

Y la expresión regular `\d+` lo único que hace es indicar un número que se repita más de una vez:

- "\d", metacaracter de número
- "+", metacaracter de "más de una vez lo que tengo a la izquierda"

Dudo mucho que eso sea la expresión científica de la regex, pero igual se entiende.

### gawk

El buen `gawk`, aunque más engorroso, también jala chido (mola mogollón):

```
ls <directorio> | awk '{ if (match($0, /[[:digit:]]+/, res)) print res[0] }'
```

Aquí el *class character* `[[:digit:]]` le indica al motor de regex de `awk`, lo mismo que a `grep -P` le indica `\d`, es decir, que *matchee* un número.

`match` es una función de `gawk` donde el contenido del primer parámetro (en nuestro caso es la línea entera ya que a la variable `$0` tiene el contenido completo del renglón entero) lo filtra según la expresión regular del segundo parámetro, y el resultado lo asigna a un array en el tercer parámetro. El tercer parámetro lo limpia y asigna el resultado en la posición número 0, y a la posición número 1 si hay paréntesis en la expresión regular expresando subgrupos, y así sucesivamente.

[Aquí su doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-match_0028_0029-function).

### sed

También podemos usar la vieja navaja suiza `sed`:

```
ls <directorio> | sed -r 's/[^0-9]//g'
```

Donde con `-r` activa las expresiones regular, y la con expresión regular de arriba, le decimos que borre todo lo que NO sea un número.

Answer (score 0):

Proponemos una solución más sencilla, dado que se pretende extraer únicamente los números que forman parte del nombre de archivo en las posiciones 7ª y 8ª.
Pasamos una expresión glob a `ls` para que solo liste los archivos con el formato adecuado (`?` sustituye a un solo carácter). Filtramos la salida con `cut`, que nos permite la opción de cortar una lista de caracteres con `-c`, en este caso el 7º y 8º:

```
ls ??_?????_??.csv |cut -c 7-8
```

Comment: El patrón ??_????? ocupa 8 posiciones. Los archivos del OP tienen 11 posiciones (XX_XXX01_XX).

Comment: ¿Puedes editar la respuesta explicando cómo funciona ese código?